# Multiply the results of 2 queries MySQL / Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have forex cross rates for 2 pairs in a MySQL table and want to calculate another comination of forex pairs from the 2

My dictionnary is:

```
    dict = {'a' : ['f','g'] , 'b' : ['f','k'] , 'c' : ['h','l'] , 'd': ['h','i'] , 'e': ['b','k'] }
```

Technically all I want to do is (for 'a' ) look for 'f' in the table, look for 'g' in the table and multiply the 2 to populate 'a' ... then do the same for 'b' , 'c' , 'd' ...

I run the following in python

```
      for x in dict :
    mycursor.execute(f"SET @Rate1 = (SELECT `Rate` FROM `param_forex` WHERE `Ticker` LIKE '{dict[x][0]}'); SET @Rate2 = (SELECT `Rate` FROM `param_forex` WHERE `Ticker` LIKE '{dict[x][1]}'); SET @Rate3 = @Rate1 / @Rate2; SELECT @Rate3;")   
        for x in mycursor:
            print(x)
```

and I get the following error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Which version of the `mysql-connector-python` library you using ?

Comment: If you are using version 2.1.4 or earlier, you should use `multi=True` to execute multiple sql queries using execute()

Comment: I am on version 2.2.9

Comment: @Tushar it still does not work. What is the other idea you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress so far (after correcting  couple of mistakes):

- Tried the `multi=true`: no more error message but nothing printing
- Tried to avoid multi and to do it for 1 item (rather than the loop)

```
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT (SELECT `Rate` FROM `param_forex` WHERE `Ticker` LIKE 'gbpeur') / (SELECT `Rate` FROM `param_forex` WHERE `Ticker` LIKE 'eurusd')")
for y in mycursor:
    print(y)
```

Now I do get an answer, even though it is not the one expected:

```
(None,)
```

When I do it directly in MySQL, it gives me 0.93 (as expected)